# How to set satoshi font in my react native expo app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, fonts

I need Satoshi font for my react native expo app. But,I don't know how i set the custom font. I follow the youtube channel methods. It doesn't work. if i install the font after i get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Expo Font package:

   `npm i expo-font`
2. Download the Satoshi font:

Download the Satoshi font from a reputable source, such as Google Fonts or [Santoshi Fonts](https://befonts.com/satoshi-font-family.html).
Save the font file in your project's `assets/fonts` directory.

3. Create a useFonts hook:

   ```
   import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

    const useSatoshiFont = () => {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
     'Satoshi': require('../assets/fonts/Satoshi.ttf'),
    });
    return fontsLoaded;
   };
   ```
4. Use the hook in your component:

   ```
   import { useSatoshiFont } from './useSatoshiFont';

    const MyComponent = () => {
    const fontsLoaded = useSatoshiFont();

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
    // Show a loading indicator while the fonts are loading
     return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
       }

      return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Satoshi' }}>This is Satoshi 
       font</Text>;
      };
   ```
5. Add the font family to your app's app.json file:

   ```
   {
     "expo": {
      "fonts": [
       {
       "name": "Satoshi",
        "style": "normal"
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   ```

- Make sure the font filename and the font family name in the app.json - file match.
- The app.json file should be located in the root directory of your project.
- Rebuild your app after making these changes.

  ```
  expo clean
  expo start
  ```

Comment: if its work then accept the the answer to help other having same problem. thank you.